# Get distance from google maps API in Angular service?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-services

I am trying to run JS version of the google maps API, because the regular API gives me a CORS issue. I am trying to find the distance and time between two destination. How do I get the data back from a service I create?

My service looks like this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class GMapsService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getData() {
    return //the data back.
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/65nuyn4b
This jsfiddle link shows how to get it done. But this is just plain JS, and I need to run it from a service, so I am confused how to include the script tag which is shown in the link, and how will it return everything back to any component where I will be subscribing to this function. Did I miss anything? I am new to Angular.

Comment: The code above misses the minimum requirements for anyone to reproduce the issue you have. [Have a look at this link please](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Next let's break down the problem into smaller chunks; you get a CORS issue so how do you call the API right now?

Answer (score 0):

if your `getData()` function returns Observable data, for example 
`return this.http.get("some url");`
then you can get the data back in another component:

```
import {GMapsService} from './serviceFileName';
export class YourComponent {
// inject your service
constructor(private myService: GMapsService) {

}

aFunction() {
this.myService.getData().subscribe((data: any) => {
  //process the returned data;
}, err => {
  console.error('GMapsService getData() fail');
});
```

}